# CRYSTAL REPORT display duplicated record

Tags: vb.net

i have write sql statement and execute it into sql studio it display result successful but to display it in crystal report record are duplicated

```
    select debit , credit , supplier.name from sales,supplier where supplied.id = sales.suuplierid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below link.It will filter all the duplicates. 
https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-filter-duplicates-by-field/